# What is the german word for ***Summation***?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, mathematics

#### Mathematiker addieren manchmal Zahlen zusammen. Was ist das Wort für "***Summation***"

[image: SCREEN CAPTURE OF A LARGE LETTER SIGMA . FLACHES BILD EINES GROßEN BUCHSTABEN-SIGMA]

```
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} $$
```

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation --> "In other languages" --> https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summe .

Comment: @marquinho: To be fair, WP only helps to find the term "Summe" itself. Figuring out how to mention it in the depicted context, i.e. along with the parameters like the value range (as the [first answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73578/5999) does perfectly), is something that is not readily available by just looking at the article title, nor is it usually listed sufficiently clearly in dictionaries.

Comment: VTC because imho this translation project is becoming unfit for this Q&A forum's format when it means that even the most basic math terms appear as a separate question here. If trying to translate LATeX, *a lot* of math terms have to be translated.

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort ist "Summe".

Der gezeigte Term spricht sich als

> Die Summe aller n von eins bis unendlich von eins durch n Quadrat

oder

> Die Summe über n gleich eins bis unendlich von eins durch n hoch zwei

Comment: Hast Du eine Referenz für die erste Variante? Ich halte sie für falsch und die zweite Variante für korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Als jemand, der unter anderem Mathematik studiert hat, würde ich hier unterscheiden:

- Der gesamte Ausdruck ist eine *Reihe* oder *unendliche Reihe*.
- Bei der Beschreibung der Reihe kommt der Begriff *Summe* vor: „Das ist die *Summe* von n gleich eins bis unendlich von eins durch n-Quadrat.“
- Der Vorgang der Summenbildung heißt *Summation*. Die Substantivierung *Summieren* ist ebenfalls gebräuchlich. Beispiel: „Bei der *Summation*/ beim *Summieren* sind die Vorzeichen zu beachten.“ Aus stilistischen Gründen nicht verwenden würde ich die Substantivierung *Summierung*.

Comment: Es gibt im Deutschen die Worte "Summierung" und "Summation". Wo würdest Du hier (bzw: generell) die Unterscheidung treffen, welches das jeweils angemessene ist? Mir kommt "Summation" in diesem Fall auch "richtiger" vor, aber Grund dafür könnte ich keinen angeben.

Comment: @bakunin, da halte ich es mit Schopenhauer: Substantivierungen mit -ung sind schlechter Stil, sofern gebräuchliche Alternativen vorhanden sind. Statt „bei der Summierung“ würde ich also „beim Summieren“ oder „bei der Summation“ schreiben. Kurzum, *Summierung* ist für mich persönlich nie angemessen (außer ich muss es, wie hier, benutzen, um darüber zu sprechen).